# How to fix error 415

Tags: html, mongodb

i'm having a problem with my html. I run my html from Eclipse and tries to enter "phone number" and "password". Both data successfully enter as json. I was going to connect my html directly to mongodb and store my data. But and error 415 came out and i don't know how to fix it.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login</a>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <div class = "container">
    <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">No Telpon</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notelpon" placeholder="No Telpon">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

</form>
 <button id="SubmitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here's my js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(){
        submit();
    });
});

function submit(){

    var submitcoy = {
        notelpon : $("#notelpon").val(),
        password : $("#password").val(),
    };

    var submitjson = JSON.stringify(submitcoy);
    console.log(submitcoy); 

    $.ajax({
          url: "/BankSinarmas/submit",
          context: document.body,
          type: 'POST',
          data: submitjson,
          contenttype: 'application./json',
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

The error was: POST (my localhost) 415()
Thanks before and have a great day.

Comment: Try removing the period after application in `contenttype: 'application./json'`

Comment: @loganrakai i tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Thankyou. I simply changed "contenttype" to "contentType" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

From the [status code section](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of the HTTP/1.1 spec:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of
>   the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for
>   the requested method.

This can happen with an invalid Content-Type HTTP header.  The correct MIME media type for JSON is `application/json`.  And as you found out your Ajax request needs the property name to be [`contentType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).